# Redhat Server oracle-rdbms.service Startup Error

Tags: sql, database, oracle, unix, redhat

I am trying to create a service file that will allow me to automatically startup my Oracle 12C database and listener automatically on reboot. I have written the service file which contains the following:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/oracle-rdbms.service

# Invoking Oracle scripts to start/shutdown Instances defined in /etc/oratab

# and starts Listener

[Unit]

Description=Oracle Database(s) and Listener

Requires=network.target

[Service]

Type=forking

Restart=no

ExecStart=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/dbstart /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/

ExecStop=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/dbshut /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/

User=oracle

[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I enabled the service and checked the status, I get the following error:

```
● oracle-rdbms.service - Oracle Database(s) and Listener
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/oracle-rdbms.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2018-10-22 11:45:02 EDT; 1 day 23h ago
  Process: 1377 ExecStop=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/dbshut /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 615 ExecStart=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/dbstart /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 22 11:45:00 oracle-dev dbstart[615]: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/dbstart: line 94: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/listener.log: Permission denied
Oct 22 11:45:02 oracle-dev dbstart[615]: touch: cannot touch ‘/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/startup.log’: Permission denied
Oct 22 11:45:02 oracle-dev dbstart[615]: chmod: changing permissions of ‘/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/startup.log’: Operation not permitted
Oct 22 11:45:02 oracle-dev dbstart[615]: Processing Database instance "orcl": log file /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/startup.log
Oct 22 11:45:02 oracle-dev dbstart[615]: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/dbstart: line 346: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/startup.log: Permission denied
Oct 22 11:45:02 oracle-dev dbshut[1377]: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/dbshut: line 63: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/listener.log: Permission denied
Oct 22 11:45:02 oracle-dev dbshut[1377]: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/dbshut: line 64: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/listener.log: Permission denied
Oct 22 11:45:02 oracle-dev dbshut[1377]: Processing Database instance "orcl": log file /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/shutdown.log
Oct 22 11:45:02 oracle-dev dbshut[1377]: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/dbshut: line 160: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/shutdown.log: Permission denied
Oct 22 11:45:02 oracle-dev systemd[1]: Started Oracle Database(s) and Listener.
```

I am logged in as root and am still not sure what the problem is. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your startup.log and listerner.log don't have the correct permissions set up. Use the `chmod` command on those two files to the appropriate permissions and it should work